# ¿Cómo podria colocar sonido a las imagenes en un Slider?

Tags: java, android-studio

Buscando en internet encontre un visor de imagenes que necesitaba, el visor esta hecho con un sliter que usa ViewFlipper, funciona muy bien.

Quisiera saber si es posible colocarle audio a cada imagen cada vez que aparece en pantalla. Es decir, cuando aparezca la imagen perro, suene el audio perro.mp3, cuando aparezca la imagen pajaro, suene el audio pajaro.mp3

En carpeta drawable coloque las imagenes y en la carpeta raw coloque los audios (perro.mp3, pajaro.mp3, etc)

¿Como hago sonar los audios del array dentro de un bucle for?

Gracias por las sugerencias.

Este es el codigo del visor de imagenes que estoy usando

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewFlipper v_flipper;

MediaPlayer sonido;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int images[] = {R.drawable.pajaro, R.drawable.perro, R.drawable.gato, R.drawable.leon};
    int audios[] = {R.raw.pajaro, R.raw.perro, R.raw.gato, R.raw.leon};

    v_flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.v_flitter);

    // for (int i = 0; i < audios.length; i++) {

    //    sonido = MediaPlayer.create(this, audios[i]).start();

    // }

    for (int image: images) {

        flipperImages(image);
        
        MediaPlayer.create(this, audios[image]).start();

    }

}


public void flipperImages(int image) {

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(image);


    v_flipper.addView(imageView);
    v_flipper.setFlipInterval(10000);
    v_flipper.setAutoStart(true);

    v_flipper.setInAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
    v_flipper.setOutAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

}

}
```

Comment: Claro que es posible. Ahora no recuerdo cómo se usa, pero [`MediaPlayer`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer) es lo que buscas.

Comment: Hola @Mateo, si, la idea es usando MediaPlayer, hacer sonar un audio con MediaPlayer es facil, lo que no he podido, es hacer sonar los audios del array en un for con MediaPlayer o con el for de las imagenes

Comment: No veo el MediaPlayer en el código. ¿Olvidaste subirlo?

Comment: Gracias @Mateo, ya coloque el código que creo debe ir (edite la pregunta), pero me genera un error **Error:(40, 67) error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to MediaPlayer**

Comment: Hola @Mateo, ya logre que no me saliera el error, pero no logro que me funcione el sonido al pasar cada imagen, tienes alguna idea? Saludos

Answer (score 1):

No sé cómo haces para pasar de vista.

En tu código vas por buen camino, solo que necesitas guardar el MediaPlayer que devuelve la función `create()` y no deberías iniciarlo hasta que quieras reproducir el sonido. Así:

```
MediaPlayer lastPlayer;
MediaPlayer[] players;
ViewFlipper flipper;

int images[] = {R.drawable.pajaro, R.drawable.perro, R.drawable.gato, R.drawable.leon};
int audios[] = {R.raw.pajaro, R.raw.perro, R.raw.gato, R.raw.leon};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    flipper = findViewById(R.id.flipper);

    players = new MediaPlayer[audios.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < audios.length; i++) {
        players[i] = MediaPlayer.create(this, audios[i]);
    }
}

public void Siguiente(View v){
    // Pasa a la siguiente vista
    flipper.showNext();

    ReproducirSonido();
}

public void Anterior(View v){
    // Pasa a la siguiente vista
    flipper.showPrevious();

    ReproducirSonido();
}

public void ReproducirSonido(){
    // Índice del MediaPlayer a reproducir
    int i = flipper.getDisplayedChild();

    try {
        // Si hay un MediaPlayer reproduciendo sonido, se para y reestablece
        if (lastPlayer != null && lastPlayer.isPlaying()){
            lastPlayer.stop();
            lastPlayer.prepare();
        }

        // Se reproduce el sonido del MediaPlayer
        lastPlayer = players[i];
        lastPlayer.start();
    }
    catch (Exception e){

    }
}
```

O si prefieres que el sonido acabe antes de poder cambiar de vista, puedes implementar [MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener), deshabilitar los botones al reproducir el audio y rehabilitarlos cuando termine en la función `onCompletion` del listener.

La ventaja de esta forma es que el MediaPlayer se reestablece al punto que solo necesitas llamar la función [`start`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#start()) para que vuelva a empezar. Así:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

    MediaPlayer[] players;
    ViewFlipper flipper;

    int images[] = {R.drawable.pajaro, R.drawable.perro, R.drawable.gato, R.drawable.leon};
    int audios[] = {R.raw.pajaro, R.raw.perro, R.raw.gato, R.raw.leon};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        flipper = findViewById(R.id.flipper);

        players = new MediaPlayer[audios.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < audios.length; i++) {
            players[i] = MediaPlayer.create(this, audios[i]);
            players[i].setOnCompletionListener(this);
        }
    }

    public void Siguiente(View v){
        // Pasa a la siguiente vista
        flipper.showNext();

        ReproducirSonido();
    }

    public void Anterior(View v){
        // Pasa a la siguiente vista
        flipper.showPrevious();

        ReproducirSonido();
    }

    public void ReproducirSonido(){
        // Índice del MediaPlayer a reproducir
        int i = flipper.getDisplayedChild();

        try {
            // Se reproduce el sonido del MediaPlayer
            players[i].start();
        }
        catch (Exception e){

        }

        // Desactiva los botones aquí
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        // Activa los botones aquí
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola @Mateo, voy a probar lo que me sugieres y te cuento, muchas gracias